# Adding javax validation to map type request body in spring webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to add javax validation to `Map` type request body in spring webflux but the validation doesn't seem to kick in.

**DummyModel.java**

```
    @Data
    public class DummyModel {

        @JsonProperty("num")
        @Min(0)
        Integer num;

    }
```

**DummyController.java**

```
    @PostMapping("/hello")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> hello(@RequestBody @Valid Mono<Map<String, DummyModel>> dummyModel) {

        ...
    }
```

It does work without the `Map` container though. My guess it the @Valid annotation is not cascaded to the `Map` params. Some combinations that i've tried were

`@RequestBody @Valid Mono<DummyModel>` - validation works

`@RequestBody @Valid Mono<Map<String, @Valid DummyModel>>` - does not work

`@RequestBody Mono<Map<String, @Valid DummyModel>>` - does not work

**Edit**:

`@RequestBody Mono<@Valid Map<String, DummyModel>>` - does not work

`@RequestBody @Valid Mono<@Valid Map<String, @Valid DummyModel>>` - does not work

Comment: And yet you haven't tried `<Mono<@Valid Map<String, DummyModel>>`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Tired `Mono<@Valid Map<String, DummyModel>>` on but still no luck.

Comment: Not sure how validation propagation on a map works. Might need to annotate both the map and the value with `@Valid`.